# C# Object reference not set to an instance of an object (bitmap problem)

Tags: c#, bitmap

111 / 5 000
Résultats de traduction
I am trying to integrate a new camera into my software but I have an error message that I do not understand.

```
 public void GetImageFromCamera()
        {
            lock (camera_stream_lock)
            {
                if (imageData != null)
                {
                    //Stop and restart stopwatch to get average fps
                    fps_stopwatch.Stop();
                    TimeSpan ts = fps_stopwatch.Elapsed;
                    current_fps = 1000.0 / (double)ts.Milliseconds;
                    fps_stopwatch.Reset();
                    fps_stopwatch.Start();

                    //var bitmapData = new BitmapDataAcquisition();

                    var image = new Bitmap(imageData.Width, imageData.Height,imageData.PixelFormat);
                    var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
                    var data = image.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, imageData.PixelFormat);
                    Marshal.Copy(imageData.Buffer, 0, data.Scan0, imageData.Buffer.Length);
                    image.UnlockBits(data);
                   
                    current_image_count++;
                    Latest_image.Source = null;
                    //Convert and save latest image
                    Latest_image.Source = NativeMethods.ToBitmapSource(image);
                }

                if (recordCameraStream && Latest_image != null)
                {
                    //recording_buffer.Add(Latest_image.Source);
                }
            }
```

I expect to receive video images from my camera but I have error messages
**error message**: systemNullReferenceExeption:Object reference not set to an instance of an object

After debugging this is where the crash  happen : **Latest_image.Source = NativeMethods.ToBitmapSource(image);**

Comment: You have something NULL. Try to debug your code to see where you get the exception

Comment: "I have error messages" - but you haven't told us any details of them. In particular, we don't know which line is failing...